# listbox bounded to collection, with table layout where each cell is an item of the collection

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, listbox, grid

I am trying to create a table which have x colums and y rows.
This table can have a item source and each cell in this table will be an item.
For exmple how to bind a images collection to table where each image is an item.
**If someone can implement this with liskbox so even better**

This is my code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Projects, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ProjectIcon, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="30" Width="30"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The control you are looking for is the `WrapPanel` from the Silverlight [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSet}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Image Source="{Binding}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: thank you.when you write items control you mean I can write instead of it a listbox for example?and how I can specify in this control that I want 4 items in each row?

Comment: @Pavel: set the width of the ItemsControl to 4 times the width of  an individual item.   However do you really have a good reason to limit yourself to 4?

Comment: it is also writes me that The type "WrapPanel" was not found because http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfix/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit is an unknown namespace.what is wrong?

Comment: @pavel: You have not installed the toolkit and then referenced the System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll?

Comment: first of all thank you for all the previous answers.I have another problem,I have only one row with alot off colums.what is the problem?

Comment: @pavel: you haven't constrained the width ItemsControl probably because you've placed it in a Scrollviewer right?

Comment: I constrained it now,The problem is that now I have not a vertical scrollviewr.I put maxHeight =400 and when the list box higher items disepear.how can I fix it?

Comment: another problem is that after I did what u said the selected item is all the items in the wrappanel.please help me :)